# Error message - "This email address is already registered"

Tags: support, accounts

When I was editing my "Display name", I got the following error message:

```
This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, 
log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.
```

---

I know what it was and why it was. It is because I'm already having an account on Stack Overflow. And, I thought of (some personal reasons) making another account, just for fun. I've tried it by using my other email, but the error still persisted there.

*To be honest with you,* I'd one more account, which I deleted few months ago due to question ban on it. So, can anyone please help me in creating the current account **along with** my already existing account?

---

> Please note that I don't want to merge [user10770365](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10770365/user10770365?tab=profile) and my existing account. But, I can accept merging [user10770365](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10770365/user10770365?tab=profile) and the banned one.

Comment: Creating a new account to circumvent a question ban is something you definitely shouldn't do. It can get you (and potentially your IP) blocked.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't use the "other gmail" to register an account? ...

Comment: @user202729 Well, I'd used it in the banned one. That's why the error is coming. Is there any way to merge this and the banned (question) account

Comment: You also said that you **do not want** to merge these accounts. This is getting confusing.

Comment: So which accounts you do want merged? How many accounts do you have?

Comment: Huh? But you had two accounts already? What do you want to create?

Comment: @user202729 yes I've two accounts, but when I try to change the display name it gives me error.

Comment: You get an error about *registering* while *changing the display name*? Now it sounds like a bug...

Comment: Try using private tab or clearing your cache/cookies/etc?

Comment: Let's merge them all from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @user202729 private tab doesn't helped. Also, I'd cleared all the cookies before logging.

Comment: @yivi Merging accounts has nothing to do with the bug...

Comment: So you're changing the display name of the user10770365 account or the banned one? Are they created using the same email?

Comment: @user202729 I want to change for the former one. Probably, I've used the same emails, I'm not sure.

Comment: @user202729 *former* was relative to your last comment. That is, user10770365 account.

Comment: Ok. Is (user10770365) question-banned or (attempted to be) deleted?

Comment: @user202729 No, it'd been just created.

Answer (score 9):

You're not going to be able to create a new account using the same login credentials as an existing account, that's by design. If you wish to have an independent account operated separately from your main account, you'll need to have different credentials for that second account.

If you wish to merge two existing accounts, please follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). If you have already deleted the other account, there's little you can do.

I should note that if we have any indications you are using this second (or third) account to do something that you cannot do with your main account alone, we will delete this second account, suspend your main account, and work to prevent you from creating others. This includes using these accounts to evade system-imposed question limits or using your accounts to vote for each other.

Comment: But the OP in fact could create the account, just could not change the display name.

Comment: @user202729 - From what I can see, they created the account using a different email, tried to switch to the same email as their main account, and are now hitting errors. This is a pretty weird edge case, because you'd need to have control over the target email address to perform the confirmation for the email address switch (you can't create a new account directly). This would only apply to someone creating two accounts and trying to do this, which I don't think I've seen before. My recommendation: use two different emails.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! **In short**, I'll not misuse these accounts. **In detail**, I'm an honest person and I hate to cheat anyone! I've been a user here for six months and I've learnt to respect the honesty. Also, I've faced one question ban and that was really a nice lesson for me. In fact, I've also helped in detecting a user who was involved in **sock puppet voting**. Therefore, I believe you can trust on me. And, if you don't, then it's good, I'll make you do so :)

Comment: I've two emails: one linked with the existing account and one with the deleted one. And, I want to use the email linked with deleted one in my new account (this one). How can I do so?

Comment: @user10770365 - Simply switch your credentials to use the other email. I believe it was the one you created the account with, so you should be able to switch back just fine. If the older account is still deleted, the email should be free to use with this account.

Comment: The error is still there